# Typescript not failing when element not found

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am using Typescript-Protractor Jasmine. When an element is not found it is not failing the test case (the 'it' block). It is showing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning though but it is still showing the script as passed.

```
   await element(by.xpath("xpath")).click().then(()=>{logObj.info("clicked")});
```

Comment: This may be due the promise is not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly handle such cases you have to work with expectation (assert).
If the click or other action is not success, that does not mean test should fail.
You have to specify when to fail.

For example:

```
it('should do something smart', async (done) => {
    await element(by.xpath('dsadadada')).click()
        .then(() => {
            logObj.info("clicked");
        })
        .catch(rejected => {
            logObj.info("it was not clicked due rejected promise");
            done.fail(rejected); // fail the test
        });

    done();
});
```

Or work with exception handling 'try catch':

```
   it('should do something smart', async (done) => {

        try {
            await element(by.xpath('dsadadada')).click(); // will throw error if not clickable
            await element(by.xpath('dsadadada')).sendKeys('dasdada'); // will throw error if cannot sendkeys

        } catch (e) {
            done.fail(e); // will fail the test if some action throw an error.
        }

        done(); // if there is no error will mark the test as success
    });
```

or with expecations

```
it('should do something smart', async (done) => {

        await element(by.xpath('dsadadada')).click(); // will throw error if not clickable
        expect(element(by.xpath('some new element on the page after click')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
        done();
    });
```

Example of encapsulated POM

```
public class PageObjectClass {
        // action of click.
        public async clickOnXBtn() {
            await await element(by.xpath('dsadadada')).click();
        }
    }

    it('do something dummy', async (done) => {
        try {
            // pageobject is class which holds the action for this button.
            const pageObject = new PageObjectClass();

            await pageObject.clickOnXBtn();
        } catch (e) {
            done.fail(e);
        }

    });
```

You can read more for POM here: 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Try catch worked for me but here is an issue. I am not writing code in 'it' block. I am writing code in a function inside a class and then calling that function inside the 'it' block. like this:

it('do something', async (done)=>{
try{
obj.methodname();
} catch(e){
done.fail(e);
}
done();

and in this case your solution is not working.

Comment: (if the answer helped you mark it ) and .. yes, thats correct. when you encapsulate smaller functions in one, work with the try catch at test level. do not put expect() at level of the page object.

Comment: i need to use methods. Can you help me how can i implement this in methods. The solution is not working when i use methods as mentioned in above comment.

Comment: I passed done as an argument in method: await pageObject.clickOnXBtn(done); then it worked for me. Thanks